# SSH with RSA keys under Raspbian keeps requesting passphrase

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

**Background information**

I am trying to connect a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) to another via SSH.
Therefore, I have generated a pair of RSA keys in my "client" Pi and saved its public key in my "server" Pi.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh pi@piserver 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

**Issue**

Whenever I try to access my sever via the command below, I am requested to provide a passphrase.

```
ssh pi@piserver
Enter passphrase for key '/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

**Further information**

Client ./ssh folder details:

```
ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  396 Feb 28 18:07 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 pi pi 1766 Feb 28 18:09 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  396 Feb 28 18:09 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  222 Feb 28 13:11 known_hosts
```

Server ./ssh folder details:

```
ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1188 Feb 28 18:27 authorized_keys
```

**Question**

How can I avoid being asked for the password all the time?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an SSH agent for this:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

on the client. This will request your password once, then remember your private key and use it whenever you connect to the server.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this so it's not necessary to use the SSH agent each time you log into the RPi?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the need to *ever* enter a passphrase you can do it this way (using "" as new_passphrase) - on the Pi:

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```