# Linux: SSH from Pi to CentOS server requires password

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, raspberry-pi

I don't have [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187418/ssh-with-rsa-keys-under-raspbian-keeps-requesting-passphrase/187435?newreg=3b1c2c30951e47d9a99484be43851ffb).  I also looked at [this article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26371/ssh-prompts-for-password-despite-ssh-authorized-keys), with no success.  I can SSH **~in~** to the Pi without issue (server -> Pi),  but I cannot do the reverse (Pi -> server) without it asking for the destination password (*NOT* passPHRASE).  I have verified that the keys are properly transferred. I used this (as we do) to do so:

```
cat .ssh/pikey_rsa.pub | ssh -tt user@server "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

but they just don't work.  Whenever I `ssh user@serverIP`, it will not just dump me in; it asks for the passsword (*NOT* passPHRASE): `user@serverIP's password:` at which point, well, I have to enter the friggin' password, defeating the entire purpose of the ssh key.

What minutia am I missing?

I should probably note that I am remoting IN to the Pi to then remote IN to the server, ala:  main -> Pi -> server.  I don't see that it should have an impact, but just to be complete, there you go.

I've rebuilt the keys six times trying to eliminate key error.  I have manually scp'd keys across and manually added them to the auth file. I tried a USB transfer for heaven's sake! I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Compare /etc/ssh/sshd_config on both systems, and post them if the answer isn't obvious.  Also, when you get the password prompt, you can enter the password and successfully log in?

Comment: `selinux` is a common source of public key auth blockage, especially if you've been fiddling around with `authorized_keys` without also fiddling around with `restorecon`

Comment: You should check the permission of ~/.ssh/authenticated_keys ,wrong permission on .ssh&authenticated_keys would cause this problem

Comment: @JimMacKenzie yep.  can totlaly login with pw.  i'll diff the configs when i get to a not-cellphone.  :)

Comment: @FrontENG permissions same on both ends: 760.

Comment: @thrig can't speak to that because...didn't ever have that be a factor before.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie files are identical save two pieces. Pi->CentOS has all the SendEnv on the CentOS end.  Pi->Ubuntu has the extra line DelegateCredentials on the Ubuntu end. i tried spinning up another server to see if a different 'nix would work.  nope.  :P

Comment: 1. Are you using `pikey_rsa` as your ssh client identity? (If you don't know then you probably aren't, and so there's no private key to match the public key you copied to the server.) 2. Do you have correct permissions and ownership for the directories from `/ ` down to `~/.ssh` on the server? (If any are writeable other than by root or the target user then that disables key-based authentication.)